# Drupal Views: Create 3-Column Home Page with Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, views

I am looking to create a 3-column home page design for my site that segregates 3 different items of a given taxonomy type (News, Training Alerts, and Advisories) into 3 separate columns. Each column shows not only the taxonomy term, but pulls the content associated with it (e.g. a teaser view of each item marked 'News').

I am not very familiar with Drupal themes, but currently I have been able to accomplish everything I've wanted with my site using the Bartik theme. Are there any ways I can accomplish this using Views and without having to change much about the Bartik theme? Or alternatively, is there a way to just create a table with PHP code that pulls the content associated with each taxonomy type into each column of a 3-column table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily with your bartik theme.
You can use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and page manager with [views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

It's not easy to use but it's worth it. There is a great screencast series in [nodeone.se](http://www.nodeone.se/sv/node/21).

To be short:

- In views: you'll make a `content pane` (not a block or page)
- With panel you can retrieve all the information from this pane and choose your layout and where you want to put all your fields inside it.
- In your case you can make `3 content pane`, each one with a specific taxonomy. After that you'll choose in which columns you'll want to put them.

[image: panel]
[image: panel]